# Crop app crash after crop

Tags: java, android

After crop Google Photos just crash. Maybe I not correctly send image or something, but it's just crash with no reason. Image in crop app looks normal. My onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            cropIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    selectedImage);

            cropIntent.setData(selectedImage);
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 7);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 9);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 450);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 350);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP_IMG);
        } else if (requestCode == RESULT_CROP_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri cropedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(cropedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            getSharedPreferences("main", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(Const.CARD_IMAGE, imgDecodableString).apply();
            photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Произошла ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

Logcat :

[image]

Comment: seems like your column index = -1

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: Please post your error message as text rather than a image

Comment: did you solve it? if not care posting full log.